# Grunt Cannot delete files outside the current working directory

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am trying to create a HelloWorld angularjs app with yeoman. After installing everything and gereration the App, I use the command grunt to start the App but I get this error

```
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Warning: Cannot delete files outside the current working directory. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I added force:true to my grunt file but I got another error

```
clean: {
      options: {
    force: true
  },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },
```

> Warning: Unable to delete ".tmp" file (EACCES: permission denied,
>   unlink '.tmp/styles'). Use --force to continue.

Comment: Please add more information about `grunt` and `yeoman`(including the generator) versions you're using.

Comment: check the documentation for `grunt-contrib-clean`, I imagine there's a `cwd` property that may address this

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```js
clean: {
 dist: {
  options: {
   force: true
  },
  files: [{
   dot: true,
   src: [
    '.tmp',
    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
   ]
  }]
 },
 server: '.tmp'
},
```